# Images showing outside of div with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a side scrolling roulette-type animation. My roll() function randomly generates a list of images beforehand, and then will scroll through them.

So that the images outside of my div aren't visible, I tried setting `overflow:hidden`, however, all images are still visible, even outside the div.

My code:

```js
function roll() {
  var tile_src = ["http://i.imgur.com/XUp8Y4r.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/Q3suBFZ.jpg"]
  var roulette = document.getElementById("roulette");
  var tiles = []

  for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    tile = document.createElement("IMG");
    tile.id = "tile"
    tile.style.position = "fixed"
    tile.style.zIndex = "-1";
    tile.src = tile_src[Math.floor((Math.random() * 2))]
    tile.style.left = $(window).innerWidth() / 2 - 64 + i * 136 + 'px';
    tile.style.top = '16px'
    tiles.push(tile)
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
    roulette.appendChild(tiles[i])
  }

}

function place_objects() {
  var ticker = document.getElementById("ticker")
  ticker.style.position = "fixed"
  ticker.style.left = $(window).innerWidth() / 2 - 16 + 'px'
  ticker.style.top = '8px'
  var roll = document.getElementById("roll")
  roll.style.position = "fixed"
  roll.style.left = $(window).innerWidth() / 2 - $("#roll").outerWidth() / 2 + 'px'
  roll.style.top = $("#ticker").height() + 16 + 'px'
  var roulette = document.getElementById("roulette")
  roulette.style.position = "fixed"
  roulette.style.left = $(window).innerWidth() / 2 - $("#roulette").outerWidth() / 2 + 'px'
  roulette.style.top = '6px'
  roulette.style.overflow = "hidden"
}

function init() {

  $(window).resize(function() {
    place_objects();
  });

  place_objects();
}

$(init)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Random Pomodoro</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    @font-face {
    font-family: "Stratum";
    src: url(Stratum2-Regular.woff) format("woff");
}

.btn {
  background: #507224;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #507224, #3a551b);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #507224, #3a551b);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #507224, #3a551b);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #507224, #3a551b);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #507224, #3a551b);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Stratum;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #2a3b16 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #728f4e;
  border: solid #64754f 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:active {
  background: #3a551b;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a551b, #507224);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3a551b, #507224);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3a551b, #507224);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3a551b, #507224);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a551b, #507224);
  border: solid #64754f 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="roulette" style="width:600px; height:144px; border:solid 2px #0f0f0f;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VMfKDyq.png" id="ticker">
  </div>
  <button class="button btn" onclick="roll()" id="roll">Roll</button>
</body>
```

For some reason my div is tiny on here. When I run it on my PC, I get this:
[image]

What I want is for only the portions of images inside the div to be visible.

Comment: Testing the code and found out the images container `div#roulette` doesn't contains a dimension setting, so it's init dimension is 4 x 4, is it normal?

Comment: @ZayLau It should have one. `<div id="roulette" style="width:600; height:144; border:solid 2px #0f0f0f;">` I think it might be something that happened when I copied it, because it works when I run it locally.

Comment: just found out you didn't assign the 'unit' to the value, so then when you control it's style via JavaScript, the browser will clear these 'invalid' value

Comment: @ZayLau Fixed that, but overflowing images are still visible.

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nu5jbc50/1/

When you apply a `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`, it is likely that such element(s) is not following the DOM tree which means those `img` are not display as children of the `div#roulette`. To get rid of that, I would add a new container `<div class="showcase" style="width: 200%; height: 100%; "></div>` after `img#ticker`

HTML:

```
<div id="roulette" style="width:600px; height:144px; border:solid 2px #0f0f0f;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VMfKDyq.png" id="ticker">
    <div class="showcase" style="width: 200%; height: 100%; "></div>
</div>
<button class="button btn" onclick="roll()" id="roll">Roll</button>
```

Instead of using `position: fixed` for the tiles, I would apply `position: relative;` to it and not assigning value to their `left` CSS property anymore, we may use the `margin-left` CSS property.

JavaScript (only the `roll()` is modified):

```
function roll() {
  var tile_src = ["http://i.imgur.com/XUp8Y4r.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/Q3suBFZ.jpg"]
  var roulette = document.getElementById("roulette");
  var $showcase = $(".showcase");
  var tiles = []

  for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    tile = document.createElement("IMG");
    tile.id = "tile"
    tile.style.position = "relative";
    tile.style.zIndex = "-1";
    tile.src = tile_src[Math.floor((Math.random() * 2))];
    //tile.style.left = $(window).innerWidth() / 2 - 64 + i * 136 + 'px';
    tile.style.top = '16px';
    if (i > 0) tile.style.margin = '0 0 0 32px';
    else tile.style.margin = '0 0 0 ' + ($(roulette).innerWidth() / 2 - 64).toString() + 'px';
    tiles.push(tile);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
    $showcase.append($(tiles[i]));
  }

}
```

also applied the following to CSS that demo the animation:

```
div.showcase > *:first-child {
  -webkit-transition: 64s linear;
  transition: 64s linear;
}
```

Call the animation via:

```
  setTimeout(function(){
    $showcase.find(">*").first().css("margin-left", ((128 * tiles.length) * -1).toString() + 'px');
  }, 1);
```